# jquery ui ddraggable : limit dragable area by pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an Image and I want to allow users to drag the image only in Y axis and I have to limit the dragging by pixels, which means users can drag only 200 pixels in Y axis (either upside and downside)

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#img" ).draggable({ axis: "y" });
  });
  </script>
```

I could limit the dragging in Y axis only but I didn't see an option to limit the dragging in pixels.

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also the option 'containment' where you can specify a bounding box with coordinates (among other options).

```
$( "#img" ).draggable({ containment: [x1, y1, x2, y2] });
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment

Here is a JSFiddle where I limit the movement of the image between 0-200 pixels on the y axis. http://jsfiddle.net/m3e6V/

Comment: but I cant move the image upwards, its moving only in downwards :(

Comment: Yes the bounding box is in absolute pixels. Currently I had it set for 0-200 in the y direction. The very top of the page is 0 px. Here is an example where I take the current position of the image and make the bounding box relative to that position. In the example I set it to 100px above the current position and 200px below. http://jsfiddle.net/m3e6V/4/