# Want to limit js draggable based on image size

Tags: javascript, css

Hello i using js draggable to move image inside a div with overflow hidden. But the movement goes beyond image size showing white bg. I want to limit the draggable movement till the end of image width or height.

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js" ></script>

 <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sample_picture" ).draggable({ axis: "x" });
  } );
  </script>

  <div style='border:solid 1px #000; width:500px; height: 500px; overflow:hidden;'>
<img src='original/20-11-2020-1605856261-36864924254_f83451c4a4_o.jpg' id='sample_picture'  style='height:100%; width:auto;object-fit:cover;'>

  </div>
```

You can replicate the issue by clicking the link below.

http://qadir.net.in/bframe4/test.php

Help me sort out this issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery ui ddraggable : limit dragable area by pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962266/jquery-ui-ddraggable-limit-dragable-area-by-pixels)